# Connect Client to EventStoreDB

Tags: c#, .net, eventstoredb

I was trying to connect 2 PC's in the same network, the first PC already has EventStoreDB server installed in version 23.6 and in the other PC I have created a console application in .NET, but when I try to read the events in the stream I get this exception:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message = Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: Unable to establish a connection as the target computer expressly denied the connection. (192.168.0.14:2113) SocketException: Unable to establish a connection as the target computer expressly denied the connection.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.Http.HttpRequestException: Unable to establish a connection as the target computer expressly denied the connection. (192.168.0.14:2113)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): A connection cannot be established as the target computer expressly denied such a connection.
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp2ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)")
  Origen = EventStore.Client
  Seguimiento de la pila:
   en EventStore.Client.Interceptors.TypedExceptionInterceptor.<AsyncUnaryCall>b__5_0[TRequest,TResponse](Task`1 t)
   en System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior ---
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior ---
   en EventStore.Client.GrpcServerCapabilitiesClient.<GetAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   en EventStore.Client.EventStoreClientBase.<GetChannelInfoExpensive>d__12.MoveNext()
   en EventStore.Client.SharingProvider`2.<FillBoxAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
   en EventStore.Client.TaskExtensions.<WithCancellation>d__0`1.MoveNext()
   en EventStore.Client.TaskExtensions.<WithCancellation>d__0`1.MoveNext()
   en EventStore.Client.EventStoreClientBase.<GetChannelInfo>d__13.MoveNext()
   en EventStore.Client.EventStoreClientBase.<GetChannelInfo>d__13.MoveNext()
   en EventStore.Client.EventStoreClient.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<<ReadStreamAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   en EventStore.Client.EventStoreClient.ReadStreamResult.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<-ctor>g__PumpMessages|0>d.MoveNext()
   en System.Threading.Channels.AsyncOperation`1.GetResult(Int16 token)
   en System.Threading.Channels.ChannelReader`1.<ReadAllAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
   en System.Threading.Channels.ChannelReader`1.<ReadAllAsync>d__12.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   en EventStore.Client.EventStoreClient.ReadStreamResult.<GetAsyncEnumerator>d__20.MoveNext()
   en EventStore.Client.EventStoreClient.ReadStreamResult.<GetAsyncEnumerator>d__20.MoveNext()
   en EventStore.Client.EventStoreClient.ReadStreamResult.<GetAsyncEnumerator>d__20.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   en Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext() en C:\Users\Yader Barahona\source\repos\ES_Consola\ES_Consola\Program.cs: línea 36
   en Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext() en C:\Users\Yader Barahona\source\repos\ES_Consola\ES_Consola\Program.cs: línea 36
```

I have already verified that the server is running on the PC where it is installed, the IP is correct along with the port 2113 and even the firewall is disabled. On the same PC where I have the server it works but when I try this it does not.

Here's the code:

```
    var settings = EventStoreClientSettings.Create("esdb://192.168.0.14:2113?tls=false");
    settings.DefaultCredentials = new UserCredentials("admin", "changeit");

    var client = new EventStoreClient(settings);

    var streamName = "shopping_cart_stream"; 

    var subscription = client.SubscribeToStreamAsync(
        streamName,
        FromStream.Start,
        async (subscription, @event, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var eventType = @event.Event.EventType;
            var eventData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(@event.Event.Data.ToArray());
            var eventMessage = $"EventType: {eventType}, Data: {eventData}";

            Console.WriteLine(eventMessage);
        }
    );

    var events = client.ReadStreamAsync(
        Direction.Forwards,
        streamName,
        StreamPosition.Start);

    await foreach (var @event in events)
    {
        var eventData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(@event.Event.Data.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(eventData);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the server configuration file look like? Does it advertise itself externally on 192.168.0.14? What http://192.168.0.14/gossip returns? Can you go to http://192.168.0.14 from the client machine and see the UI?

Comment: I tried to look for that file but I can't find it, I installed the eventstoredb using the "choco" command, and as for the UI I can only see it from the pc that has the eventstoredb installed with the same code that I have provided if it works on "localhost:2113" but I still can't access it from the other pc as a client.

Comment: It should be possible for you to find where Chocolatey installs packages on your machine, the default used to be `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey`. The server might be bound to the loopback address and it causes it not being reachable remotely.

Comment: I created another post because it did not let me put so many characters in the comment

Comment: On SO you should not add question updates as answers, the answer will be downvoted and potentially deleted. You can just update the question. Also, all the images aren't visible without clicking on them.

Comment: And, indeed, it looks like it's bound to the loopback address and that's why you can't access it from another machine. Do you actually need to install it for playing around, why can't you run it in Docker? We have all the things you need in the docs.

Comment: I have already solved the problem, thank you very much for your help 
Alexey Zimarev. Sorry for the new post.
In case anyone needs this, what I did was to change the external ip to 0.0.0.0.0 so that the server listens on all interfaces and so from the client I could connect to the server :)